# iterating over row and column and replace values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

1. How do we divide all numeric values by 10 in the entire pandas dataframe lying between  10 and 100?

conditions:

1. Time or any non-numeric column to be ignored.
2. The numbers can lie in any row or column.

| `time` | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | `40` |
| 12:50 | 5 | 6 | `70` | 8 |
| 13:50 | `80` | 7 | 6 | 500 |

Use this code if need be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
data_1 = {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 80],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 70 ,6],
          'n4': [40, 8, 500],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df1
```

**Try 1:** It doesn't seem to work

```
j = 0
k = 0
for i in df:
    if df[j][k] > 10 and df[j][k] < 100:
        df[j][k] = df[j][k] / 10
        j = j + 1
    else:
        pass;
    k = k + 1
```

**Expected Result:**

1. Since 80, 70, 40 are the numbers lying between 10 and 100, they are all replaced by x/10 in the same dataframe.

- 80 --> 80/10 = 8
- 70 --> 70/10 = 7
- 40 --> 40/10 = 4

2. Entire column of time is ignored as it is non-numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DataFrame.applymap` is pretty slow when working with a big data set, it doesn't scale well. You should always look for a vectorized solution if possible.

In this case, you can mask the values between 10 and 100 and perform the conditional replacement using [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) (or [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) if you negate the condition).

```
# select the numeric columns
num_cols = df1.select_dtypes(include="number").columns

# In DataFrame.mask `df` is replaced by the calling DataFrame, 
# in this case df = df1[num_cols]
df1[num_cols] = (
    df1[num_cols].mask(lambda df: (df > 10) & (df < 100), 
                       lambda df: df // 10)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1

    time  n1  n2  n3   n4
0  11:50   1   2   3    4
1  12:50   5   6   7    8
2  13:50   8   7   6  500
```

Setup:

```
time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
data_1 = {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 80],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 70 ,6],
          'n4': [40, 8, 500],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
```

Comment: @n3a5p7s9t1e3r I corrected `DataFrame.mask` instead of `DataFrame.where`, I was misreading the output you wanted ;) They are very similar methods, the "inverse" of each other.

Comment: thank you! I'll keep this in mind. This one answer taught me alot about working larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df1[['n1','n2','n3','n4']].applymap(lambda x : x/10 if 10 < x < 100 else x)
    n1  n2  n3  n4
0   1.0 2   3.0 4.0
1   5.0 6   7.0 8.0
2   8.0 7   6.0 500.0
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks.

can we use df1[[1:4]].applymap(lambda x : x/10 if 10 < x < 100 else x)?

Comment: @n3a5p7s9t1e3r you can use `iloc` method: `df1.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda x : x/10 if 10 < x < 100 else x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the columns which have numeric datatypes, use `.applymap()` to perform the division operation, and then reassign back to the original dataframe. Notably, this doesn't require hardcoding the columns you want to transform in advance:

```py
numerics = df1.select_dtypes(include="number")
numerics = numerics.applymap(lambda x: x // 10 if 10 < x < 100 else x)
df1[numerics.columns] = numerics
```

This outputs:

```py
    time  n1  n2  n3   n4
0  11:50   1   2   3    4
1  12:50   5   6   7    8
2  13:50   8   7   6  500
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
def repl(df, cols):
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x//10 if x >= 10 and x <= 100 else x)
    return df

new_df = repl(df1, ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'])
new_df
```

Output:

```
   time   n1    n2  n3  n4
0   11:50   1   2   3   4
1   12:50   5   6   7   8
2   13:50   8   7   6   500
```